How to add google recaptcha v2 in php form script
I use following php email sending script at my contact form, I want to add google recaptcha V2 in this form. Can any one help me in this. My form working perfectly when I send emails throgh it but spam emails are coming in, so I want to add some spam protection for this, by using google recaptcha. I would appreciate if anyone can help me out with this problem.
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    {
        $secret = 'secret-key';
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success)
        {
            $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
        }
        else
        {
            $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        }
    }

    // REPLACE THIS 2 LINES AS YOU DESIRE
    $email_to = "info@armstextile.com";
    $email_subject = "You've got a new submission";

    function problem($error)
    {
        echo "Oh looks like there is some problem with your form data: <br><br>";
        echo $error . "<br><br>";
        echo "Please fix those to proceed.<br><br>";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if (
        !isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])||
        !isset($_POST['phone'])||
        !isset($_POST['subject'])
    ) {
        problem('Oh looks like there is some problem with your form data.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
        $error_message .= 'Email address does not seem valid.<br>';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
        $error_message .= 'Name does not seem valid.<br>';
    }

    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'Message should not be less than 2 characters<br>';
    }

    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        problem($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details following:\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: " . clean_string($message) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: " . clean_string($phone) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: " . clean_string($subject) . "\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    ?>

    Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible.


    <?php
}
?>

form html code
<div class="contact-wrap">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-30">
                    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-30">
                    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-30">
                    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-30">
                    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-12 mb-35">
                    <textarea class="from-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site-key"></div>
            <div class="btn-part">
                <div class="form-group mb-0">
                    <div class="btnblack"><span class="btn-text"> <span><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT NOW" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"></span></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="form-messages"  class="alert alert-secondary bg-white no-border"></div>
</div>


What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? Remember that Stackoverflow isn't a tutorial provider or a free write-my-code service. We'll help you with your attempt to implement your requirement, if you encounter a specific issue. Recaptcha is well documented online, and existing examples exist showing how to integrate it with PHP as well. Have you done any research? Reminder: [ask]

I add google recaptcha code in my script but it is not working, emails are still sending without recaptcha check.

Well, what else did you expect? Looking at your code, the only thing you do when the recaptcha verification fails is set a string variable called $errMsg. You never do anything to actually stop the script proceeding, or prevent the email being sent, or anything. You never even use $errMsg again after that. I guess you just pasted some random code you found without thinking through how it needs to work within the context of your own code...to integrate other people's code into your script you need to do more than just blindly paste it without analysis - you usually need to adapt it a bit

P.S. As an aside, this: $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" . is going to cause you problems with your emails. The $email values comes from the user input. But your script doesn't have permission to send emails on the user's behalf. (for example, if your website's domain is xyz.com and a user submits abc@gmail.com as their email, your website clearly is not allowed to send emails from gmail - only gmail can do that.). This is a great way to get your emails marked as fakes or spam, and your domain blocked. Instead use a fixed "from" address on your domain - e.g. donotreply@xyz.com

I'm guessing you got some of this email sending code from some bad, obsolete or incompetent tutorial. Sadly there are far too many of those online. Suppressing errors with @ (e.g. @mail...) is also a bad idea usually. Then if the mail function fails, you'll never know, and emails will just seem to disappear with no obvious cause. This does not help you to debug or diagnose problems in your code! Also these days most people would recommend using a good library like PHPMailer to handle constructing emails in PHP rather than building raw strings for the clunky old mail() function.

For the recaptcha validation it would probably make sense if you replaced else         { $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.'; } with else { problem("Robot verification failed, please try again"); }. You also need to account for the case where $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] isn't even set. At the moment in that scenario your code just carries on as if nothing happened. So you need another else block for that as well

P.S. I hope you didn't just share your real recaptcha secret key with the entire world....maybe time to cancel it and get a new one from google

Hint: Put exit(); after recaptcha checking failed (or better, alert the user and then exit(); )

@KenLee that's what the OP's problem() function already does...hence why I suggested that they put it to some use
